# How to measure the distance from pi NOIR CAMERA MODULE and the object

Tags: hardware, raspicam, pi-2

i need to measure the distance between the pi camera module and the object , i've found this formula

```
distance to object (mm) = focal length (mm) * real height of the object (mm) * image height (pixels)
                          ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
                          object height (pixels) * sensor height (mm)
```

i have found that for the pi NoIR we have :

> Focal length : 3.60 mm +/- 0.01
>
> real height of the object : i'm capturing people so it can be between 150 cm and 200 cm
>
> image height (pixels) : 1944 (true ??)
>
> object height (pixels) : ??
>
> sensor height :3.67 x 2.74 mm (so the height should be 2.74 mm)

I found some parameters in the camera docs but i need your help for the others that marked with "?"

http://elinux.org/Rpi_Camera_Module
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/camera.md

thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Object height in pixels is what you measure in the captured images, based on this you can calculate the distance to the object.

You can rearrange the formula into

`distance to object (mm) =  some constant (mm*pixels)
                           ----------------------
                           object height (pixels)`

and then determine the constant from a few measurements with the object at different, known distances.

**Update: measuring the object height in an image**

I have only used [simpleCV](http://simplecv.org/) in Python, which I heard is easier to use than openCV directly. For determining the object height, I would try the following steps.

- detect the object. This is easiest if the object has a distinct color from  the background. Look at the openCV tutorials, and adapt their example code. Try colordistance from the color of the object.
- do blob detection, where the idea is to find and isolate the object from the rest of the image
- once the object is a "blob" you should be able to measure its properties, e.g. the height.

If you can choose the object yourself, it would be easy if you choose a sphere, since then the size in the image will not depend on the orientation (rotation) of the object.

Comment: i can't figure out  what is the difference between real height of the object and object height and why it's in pixels > thanks

Comment: well, real height of the object (mm) is just the height of the object itself, in millimeters. Object height (pixels) is how many pixels high it is on the camera's image.

Comment: and so what is the difference between object height (px) and image height (px) :p

Comment: Image height (px) is the number of pixels in the image sensor in the vertical direction. Together with sensor height (mm) they are used to find how high one single physical pixel is on the sensor.

Comment: i have found sensor height but i didn't understand well your answer , are you talking about  Pixel size : it's 1.4 µm x 1.4 µm !!! and what about object height --> thanks a lot

Comment: Indeed, the pixel size (height) is 1.4 µm, which you can find by dividing the sensor height (mm) by the number of pixels in the sensor in the vertical direction. This is the reason those two quantities appear in the formula. If you want to know *why*, find a diagram explaining why the formula looks the way it does. (Link to the source?) If you just want the answer, insert the specified values. For object height (px), I assume you take a photo of the object with the Pi Cam, count how many pixels it occupies in the vertical direction. The closer it is, the bigger it will be in the picture.

Comment: ok now i neeed to measure the distance in real time from the pi camera ... how can i get the object height , is there a function in opencv that can i use ?  the source is from an answer found in stackoverflow  but i haven't save the link